# Actionscript 2 and Actionscript 3 working together possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Basically this is the situation I'm in, I have an AS2 file that links and opens up an AS3 file using the loadMovieNum("file.swf",0) command that works fine. In the AS3 file that's open I have a button that links back to the AS2 file using the loader class and removing child to load the original AS2 file back on screen which it does seem to do fine.

However the only problem I'm having is now that some of the functionality in my original AS2 file when reloaded doesn't seem to 100% work properly as it did once first loaded in i.e particular some of the buttons.

I'm trying to achieve something here which is just too complex or not even possible to do and would I be better off just rewriting my whole project in AS3? (Something I don't really want to do at the moment due to time constraints)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, mixing ActionScript 2 and 3 is not a good thing to do, especially with AS2 being the “parent”. As you seem to make calls from AS2 to AS3, and back to AS2, I guess that it simply breaks after all. So yeah, the solution would be to make at least that parent script in AS3. Try to split your project up more, and maybe you can avoid having to rewrite everything.

> - SWF files written in ActionScript 1.0 or 2.0 cannot load SWF files written in ActionScript 3.0. This means that SWF files authored in Flash 8 or Flex Builder 1.5 or earlier versions cannot load ActionScript 3.0 SWF files.
>
>   The only exception to this rule is that an ActionScript 2.0 SWF file can replace itself with an ActionScript 3.0 SWF file, as long as the ActionScript 2.0 SWF file hasn't previously loaded anything into any of its levels. An ActionScript 2.0 SWF file can do this through a call to `loadMovieNum()`, passing a value of `0` to the `level` parameter.
> - In general, SWF files written in ActionScript 1.0 or 2.0 must be migrated if they are to work together with SWF files written in ActionScript 3.0. For example, suppose you created a media player using ActionScript 2.0. The media player loads various content that was also created using ActionScript 2.0. You cannot create new content in ActionScript 3.0 and load it in the media player. You must migrate the video player to ActionScript 3.0.
>
>   If, however, you create a media player in ActionScript 3.0, that media player can perform simple loads of your ActionScript 2.0 content.

[source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d9e.html)